# how can i hide the toggle div after postback in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, css

This is my Script Code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var $content = $(".contentPersonalDetail").hide();
        $(".togglePersonalDetail").on("click", function (e) {
            $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
            $content.slideToggle();
        });
    });
```

I have gone through some answer but I am weak in javascript so I don't know how to implement, like storing the value in hiddenfield and access it but I don't know how to do that. or any other solutions?

Comment: Its always hide the div. i dont want to hide the after postback

Comment: The "toggle div"? Do you have a div that looks like <div id="toggle"> that you want to hide?

Comment: i have panel. in that one i have to show and hide the panel body. but when i click on submit button(postback) the panel body always hide. so i want to prevent that.

Comment: <div class="togglePersonalDetail"> on click

Comment: Your JQuery looks correct for that class, assuming it's actually on the view when it loads. Are you getting any errors in the browser debugger?

Comment: Which div are you talking about? In your question you ask how to hide the div after post but in your comment above you say you do not want to hide after post--I think you need to be more clear about what you want.

Comment: If the form is already loaded, you should put your hide into the AJAX Done

Comment: No Error, I just want To Prevent hide the div every time of postback

Comment: yes yoshi by mistake i post hide thats why i clarify in commnet.

Answer (score 0):

Use Button Inside the UpdatePanel.. it will Restrict the Page Load or PostBack Event..

Comment: You could add some code sample for completeness of your answer.